# How to insert dash (-) into database using wpdb and new_to_publish hook?

Tags: mysql, wpdb, title, table

I am saving titles of posts in a separate table for a specific use.
The titles are saved to the database when a post is published.
code is:

```
add_action('future_to_publish', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
function send_emails_on_new_event($post)
    {
        global $post;
        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = 'tbl_name';   
        $site_post_url = get_permalink();
        $site_post_title = get_the_title();
        $author_id = $post->post_author;
        $author = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id );    
        $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
                                                    'site_post_url' => $site_post_url,
                                                    'site_post_title' => $site_post_title,                                          
                                                    'Author' => $author                                         
                                                ) );

    }
```

The above code insert the data to proper fields in the table called 'tbl_name'
all fine except `site_post_title` 
if the `site_post_title` has `dash -` it is automatically converted to hyphen code and saved.

Let's say my title is **- Dash - test - -ok?**

when I check the record in the table `tbl_name` it is `- Dash &#8211; test &#8211; -ok?`

[image: tbl]
Why those two dashes are saved like that?

how can I save dashes as just dashes in the database table?

**UPDATE**

title **number sign # double quotes " slash / colon :** is  saved as `number sign # double quotes &#8221; slash / colon :`

Comment: A `dash` is a symbol. A symbol is (depending on your charset) defined as a Unicode. So what you see is a unicode of a symbol.

Comment: my charset is `UTF-8` and why only two dashes from this title are converted to `unicode of a symbol` ? how can I fix this?

Comment: why other symbols like `:` or `/` are NOT converted as `unicode of a symbol`

Comment: This is probably `wptexturize()` on the post title through the `the_title` filter from `get_the_title()`. To test, try e.g. `$post->post_title` instead

Comment: I don't understand the question as the title do not match the snippet. Is your problem is with inserting dash to the DB or having the title normalized? If the former it will be very surprising, with the later then the answer will probably be "ok, that is how it titles are designed to work". So what is exactly the question, is it to explain why it is removed or to look for a workaround?

Comment: @FoolishCoder `:` and `/` are no Symbol characters as I believe!

Comment: @birgire Thanks a lot. That works.. I've replaced `$site_post_title = get_the_title();` to `$site_post_title = $post->post_title;` and now the **dashes, double quotes** are not converted to `unicode of the symbol` Thoses are saved in the (custom) table as just the title has **dashes, double quotes**. Make it as answer.. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we call `get_the_title()`, then the *post title* is taken through the `wptexturize()` function via the `the_title` filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
```

The *en-dash* and *em-dash* are replaced with

```
/* translators: en dash */
$en_dash = _x( '&#8211;', 'en dash' );
/* translators: em dash */
$em_dash = _x( '&#8212;', 'em dash' );
```

A simple workaround to keep the en/em dashes when you store it to your custom table, could be:

```
$site_post_title = str_replace( 
    [ '&#8211;', '&#8212;' ], 
    [ '–', '—' ],
    get_the_title()
);
```

or just use the raw `$post->post_title` if that's makes more sense for your setup.